# Pen drive not mounting

Tags: mount, fstab

This worked earlier, but no longer works.??

```
andy7_~$ mount /media/andy/KINGSTON_DRIVE/
mount: /media/andy/KINGSTON_DRIVE/: No such file or directory
andy7_~$ sudo mount /media/andy/KINGSTON_DRIVE/
[sudo] password for andy: 
mount: /media/andy/KINGSTON_DRIVE/: can't find in /etc/fstab.
andy7_~$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="3145bcdb-283c-4de7-af8c-cf4c6f3ef349" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b0acda74-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MAXTOR_SDB1" UUID="b3b0f384-9e2e-45f5-8995-932f1113f59d" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="000f0791-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="MAXTOR_SDB2" UUID="8adebdf0-6bc3-4eee-8363-3e9440688d42" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="000f0791-02"
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="MAXTOR_SDB5" UUID="fd00f2d7-d666-4614-885d-5ace942dd3f6" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="000f0791-05"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="KINGSTON_DRIVE" UUID="082abda7-a0e5-4f0b-9ce3-fd12fa8ee01d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1b95dfd9-01"

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3145bcdb-283c-4de7-af8c-cf4c6f3ef349 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=fd00f2d7-d666-4614-885d-5ace942dd3f6     /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB5   ext3
UUID=b3b0f384-9e2e-45f5-8995-932f1113f59d      /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1   ext3
UUID=8adebdf0-6bc3-4eee-8363-3e9440688d42      /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB2   ext3
UUID=082abda7-a0e5-4f0b-9ce3-fd12fa8ee01d     /dev/sdc1                  ext4 
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you imagine should be mounted on `/media/andy/KINGSTON_DRIVE/`?

Comment: `/media/andy/KINGSTON_DRIVE/` is a "mount point", the `mount` command wants a "device" to be mounted on a "mount point". If the "mount point" is defined in `/etc/fstab`, one can use the "mount point" with `mount`. `/media/andy/KINGSTON_DRIVE/` looks like a directory created by automounting a recently inserted a USB key.

Comment: It is in my fstab.